# Moving average method VB

Tags: vb.net

i'd try to make moving average in vb
[i want to check the cells and set the value to text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2AC.png)

but the result  is [all the text box has the same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ecp.png)

how to make my first check value (penjualan/bulan) is inputed into first text box and the second check (penjualan/bulan) to second text box.
here is my code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
            tb1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
            tb2.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
            tb3.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        End If
    End Sub
```

thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  All facts pertinent to your question need to be in the question; and some effort to resolve it yourself is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set EVERY time the `cellClicked-event` is raised all 3 Textboxes to the same value, `CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value`.
 Another problem is that your code will set the text in the Textboxes always. It dont check if the Checkbox is checked or not. it just updated every time you click in any cell in this column, the text in the 3 boxes to the value of your currently selected row.

Here you have a solution. Its not perfect but should work, although you should try to understand and optimize it.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitializeDgv()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeDgv ()
        Dim row as String() = New String(){"2016",240}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        row = New String(){"2017",223}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        row = New String(){"2015",54}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        if e.ColumnIndex=2

            Dim checkedRows=(From dgv as DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows where dgv.Cells(2).Value=True select dgv).ToList()
            Dim controlsList As new List(of TextBox)
            controlsList.Add(TextBox1)
            controlsList.Add(TextBox2)
            controlsList.Add(TextBox3)
            for Each item in controlsList
                item.Text=String.Empty
            Next
            for i=0 to checkedRows.Count-1
                controlsList(i).Text=checkedRows.Item(i).Cells(0).Value
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```